# HTML/CSS White spaces still present even after commenting new lines

Tags: html, css

This very simple html structure

```
<div id="s1container"><!--
    --><div class="s1box"></div><!--
--></div>
```

which has been commented to try to delete white spaces between the elements, with the following css still produces an unwanted padding in the bottom between both elements

```
    #s1container {
        background: gray;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .s1box {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: #ccc;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
```

As you can see from this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/um1L4c0t/

The only way to ameliorate this problem, is to set the font-size to 0em on the parent and set it back to 1em to the children, which is not a solution considering i'm extensively using em units for the boxes dimensions, the nesting property of ems would make that kind of layout impossible if the parent's font-size is set to 0em

Why is the white space still present even after commenting out the white spaces between those elements?

Comment: In chrome at least adding content to `.slbox` even an `&nbsp;` seems to remove the white space afterwards https://jsfiddle.net/um1L4c0t/1/ unsure why. Worth noting though I don't think the comments have anything to do with the issue

Comment: works on firefox also, i'm not sure what's the magic behind this

Comment: Could just hack it in with a pseudo element I guess if you want - shouldn't mess with the layout too much: `.s1box:after{ content: "\a0"; }` https://jsfiddle.net/um1L4c0t/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments take out the right white space, `vertical-align: top;` get rid of the bottom.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#s1container {
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
}

.s1box {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="s1container"><!--
--><div class="s1box"></div><!--
--></div>
```

---

A more modern approach is to use `flexbox`, where you get the good from both worlds

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#s1container {
  background: gray;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
}

.s1box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="s1container">
 <div class="s1box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you please explain why commenting the whitespaces didn't work and why is it necessary to use vertical-align ?

Comment: @RowRebel Inline elements behaves as characters, and such have a white space on its right/bottom, so characters won't collapse into each other. There is many ways to get rid of them, and `vertical-align` is one. You can read more here, [css-white-space/](https://www.impressivewebs.com/css-white-space/), and here [white-space-image-elements-inline-elements-descenders/](https://mor10.com/removing-white-space-image-elements-inline-elements-descenders/)

Comment: @RowRebel Added a second approach to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove display: inline-block; and use margin: 0 auto;

Comment: this is an overly simplified example, display: inline-block is needed in the actual implementation of the website